# Why bcrypt library CompareHashAndPassword method is slow?

Tags: go, bcrypt

I want to compare password and use `bcrypt` library but  `CompareHashAndPassword`  method is very slow. Why this method is slow?

```
var b  []byte =  []byte("1234")
 var bx  []byte =  []byte("$2a$14$RWV9NhWmlQmSoV9toM/k9OIzaNcYssCiauPVAljiX2NGhqvyxcOMy")
 fmt.Println("Start Compare: ", time.Now().Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05.000000"))
 err := bcrypt.CompareHashAndPassword(bx, b)
 fmt.Println("Completed Compare: ", time.Now().Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05.000000"))
 fmt.Println("------------------------")
```

Result:

> Start Compare:  2018-03-22 22:53:09.142380
>
> Completed Compare:  2018-03-22 22:53:10.347585

Can you help me?

Comment: bcrypt is supposed to be slow, that's the whole point. The time it takes completely depends on the system and the available cpu cycles.

Comment: which library do you recommend for password encryption ? because bcrypt lib is very slow

Comment: That's the point. A fast library for key encryption would be useless. Being slow is what makes it secure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Slowness is a design feature of bcrypt, because if it was fast, it would be easy to brute-force password hashes. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt):

> Besides incorporating a salt to protect against rainbow table attacks, bcrypt is an adaptive function: over time, **the iteration count can be increased to make it slower**, so it remains resistant to brute-force search attacks even with increasing computation power.

Comment: ok, i write  a simple web application,which encryption algorithm do you recommend to use(md5 ,sha512,...)?

Comment: Use bcrypt. It's specifically designed for password hashing.

Comment: OP is asking because he wants to authorize user passwords. I am here for the same reason. If it takes 10 seconds to authorize a user password, then my loading time is slow af. So what's the point to authorize a user, if he leaves from my site anyway because the login time is ridiculously big?

What the OP asks (judging from his comments) is if there is a better way to authorize and what he's doing wrong or if he's supposed to use another library. So am I :D

Answer (score 2):

When developing and testing I lower the cost of bcrypt to make it run faster

e.g:

```
hashPassword, _ := bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword([]byte(password), 4)
"$2a$04$gZUB3tTcsht5JehP3jVxCeOVZSOGzy5ztfXh1kSbp3EDzEXCCH5v."
```

That line runs very fast compared with my usual cost value of 14

So then, when you are comparing, bcrypt reads the cost of your hash and evaluates.

In your example I see that you use cost 14 to generate that hash

```
[]byte("$2a$14$RWV9NhWmlQmSoV9toM/k9OIzaNcYssCiauPVAljiX2NGhqvyxcOMy")
```

Maybe lowering the cost will work for you too.

Comment: +1 for considering the 2nd argument (cost) of the Generate function, keeping in mind that you should find a balance between speed and security. A good read on this subject can be found here: [Recommended # of rounds for bcrypt](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17207/recommended-of-rounds-for-bcrypt/83382#83382)